# On the automorphisms of the unitary group in the strong operator topology

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, topological-groups, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be an infinite dimensional complex (or real) Hilbert space, and let $U(H)$ be the unitary (or orthogonal) group. We equip $U(H)$ with the strong topology.
Now, suppose that $\phi: U(H) \rightarrow U(H)$ is a continuous group automorphism.

> Is it true that $\phi$ is automatically continuous with respect to the norm topology on $U(H)$?

I tried proving this directly, but I did not get very far.
Next, I tried characterizing the automorphisms of $U(H)$ more abstractly.
I vaguely recall reading somewhere that any automorphism $\phi$ of $U(H)$ can be realized by conjugation by either an element of $U(H)$ itself, or by conjugation by a conjugate linear isometry of $H$, which would thus automatically imply that $\phi$ is continuous with respect to the norm topology, but I haven't been able to find this result or prove it myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This result is true, and is surprisingly (to me) nontrivial. One reference I could come up with is the paper " Transformations of the unitary group on a Hilbert space" by L. Molnar and P. Semrl. Please look at Theorem 2.5 in this paper : https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/386f/31da52d66592ccee13ed046cac4d9ed2444f.pdf

The authors credit the result to M. Broise "Commutateurs dans le groupe unitaire d’un facteur"(Cor 3).

(I didn't check Broise's paper though, as it's in a language that I can't read :)).

Comment: I find your lack of faith ... disturbing

Comment: @YemonChoi: :D I read that in the voice of Vader himself!